# As an expat, can you rely on travel insurance in case of the Coronavirus becoming a widespread major pandemic?

Tags: health, insurance, covid-19

I was wondering, do regular travel healthcare insurance policies contain a clause which excludes coverage in extreme situations/disasters usually? I'm thinking about a global pandemic of the SARS-CoV-2/coronavirus as an example. For context, I'm from Germany.

I know it is a whole different question, if you can *actually* get any medical assistance in case of a major breakout.

To be clear: Not asking because I'm in need of medical help - I just want to understand what the policies look like.

Comment: I suspect your question may be closed as too broad. FWIW, the second exclusion listed in my own travel insurance is ‘epidemic/pandemic’. This might help https://www.travelinsurancereview.net/tips-and-advice/understanding-travel-insurance/what-is-not-covered/

Comment: Yeah, I had this feeling too. It's not a simple thing to answer. Thanks for sharing your case

Comment: Can you clarify “as an expat”? Travel insurance will usually not cover you in your country of residence or beyond a certain duration...

Comment: I'm not a resident - technically a tourist. Afaik it shouldn't become an issue when I stay too long here (Georgia).

Comment: Coronavirus is already a widespread major pandemic.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to understand what the policies look like.

They are all different, so you need to read the exclusions of the one that you have or plan on getting. They also get updated frequently. I checked a few today and about half of them to claim during the booking process that they cover Coronavirus related medical expenses. Interesting enough, it was quite cheap, so it doesn't seem like the insurance companies think this is a big risk.